# R to specify printing of missing values in format

Tags: r

I'm using `format` to create readable flat tables for which `ftable` is not sufficient. The one caveat is that in calculating column frequencies using the `prop.table` function, `NA` values are printed as `NA` when this causes clutter and low readability.

How can I modify code like the following to print `NA` or `NaN` values using blank space or a period? I considered using the `sub` function, but I believe it's messy and prone to errors if column names contain those character values.

```
x <- sample(c(1, 2, 3), 100, replace=TRUE)
y <- sample(factor(c(1, 2), levels=1:3), 100, replace=TRUE)
t <- table(x,y)
p <- prop.table(t, margin=2)
o <- structure(
  paste(format(t), '(', format(round(100*p)), '%)'),
  dim=dim(t),
  dimnames=dimnames(t)
)
```

This is the example output given:

```
> o
   y
x   1             2             3            
  1 "20 (  38 %)" "21 (  44 %)" " 0 ( NaN %)"
  2 "20 (  38 %)" "16 (  33 %)" " 0 ( NaN %)"
  3 "12 (  23 %)" "11 (  23 %)" " 0 ( NaN %)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- sample(c(1, 2, 3), 100, replace=TRUE)
 y <- sample(factor(c(1, 2), levels=1:3), 100, replace=TRUE)
 t <- table(x,y)
 p <- prop.table(t, margin=2)
 p <- round(100*p,digits=0)
 p[is.na(p) ] <- " "
 o <- structure(
    paste(format(t), '(', format(p), '%)'),
    dim=dim(t),
    dimnames=dimnames(t)
  )
 o
#-------------------------
   y
x   1            2            3           
  1 "17 ( 34 %)" "14 ( 28 %)" " 0 (    %)"
  2 "15 ( 30 %)" "17 ( 34 %)" " 0 (    %)"
  3 "18 ( 36 %)" "19 ( 38 %)" " 0 (    %)"
```

Replace the blank (" ") with any string you want.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to parse through rows and columns (if your data isn't big):

```
no_row=nrow(o)
no_col=ncol(o)

for(rows in 1:no_row){
  for(cols in 1:no_col){
    o[rows,cols]<-sub(pattern = "NaN", replacement = "0",  x = o[rows,cols])
    }
}
```

But of course there are simple better ways to do it. :)
Above code output is:

```
> o
   y
x   1             2             3          
  1 "17 (  31 %)" "13 (  29 %)" " 0 ( 0 %)"
  2 "16 (  29 %)" "21 (  47 %)" " 0 ( 0 %)"
  3 "22 (  40 %)" "11 (  24 %)" " 0 ( 0 %)"
```

Hope it will help!